# Feasible to extend WebChat control to connect with Signal R

Tags: signalr, botframework

I have a use case where I want to build a portal for Agent Login and Registry and allow conversation to be transferred from Bot to an agent.

Looking at this article for possibilities -
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2017/08/10/microsoft-bot-framework-handing-off-to-a-human-for-agentssupervisors-with-c-and-the-botbuilder-sdk/

The handoff should happen from customer using webchat and bot logic is coded in C#. The steps that I could think of -

- User asks for handoff
- The Bot logic connects the conversation to signalr hub on server side
- The next conversation takes place directly using this hub.

Need to know if someone implemented such use case. What should be approach for creating this?

Answer (score 0):

Look over the [intermediator bot sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample). It is designed to work with v4 of the BotFramework demonstrating bot-to-human hand-off in C#. You will, of course, need to adapt it to work with SignalR. But, I don't see any reason it couldn't be configured to do so.

Comment: I have seen intermediator bot sample, it says the user and agent has to be on different channels. But let's say if we would want to have user using webchat and agents also using a web based portal to login and pick up the chat. That use case changes the implementation thought process.